Digital Beamforming performance issues - ADC and DAC clipping
Digital Beamforming when compared with analog beamforming provides many benefits in terms of performance and flexibility. It is however more complex and each antenna will have its own frontend and own DAC and ADC.
If the design or component limitations necessitate clipping the different DACs or ADCs, how  would that impact the performance?
To be more specific, would the Intermod components generated by clipping add coherently or noncoherently?
In general and talking about Tx, one would expect that the intermod generated in the different power amplifiers would add noncoherently (at least this is my assumption), would that be different when it comes to the intermod generated because of the DAC(s) clipping, and if yes why?
Would clipping on the different ADCs in the Rx be in any way different than DAC clipping?

From a Tx perspective, first remember that beamforming relies on the phase relationship between the transmitters in the array.  When you clip the output signal, you not only change the amplitude but also can affect the phase.  You are injecting noise from the harmonics of your fundamental frequency, but your big problem is the phase shift you are causing.
You can perform this simple experiment to demonstrate: generate a file with sampled data describing a pure sine wave and run an FFT on it.  Then clip the waveform and repeat and compare the phase.  You will note that the phase at the fundamental frequency shifts unless the clipping is perfectly symmetrical.  The greater the asymmetry of the clipped signal, the larger the phase shift, and the stronger the effect will be on the degradation of of your beam.  In the real world, absolute symmetry of clipping is may not be realistic.  But, however you clip, you can see the effect on any element of the array from any distorted waveform by examining the phase and amplitude of the fundamental portion of the waveform.  You will also have a higher filtering burden on the receiving end due to the extra harmonics.
From an Rx perspective, there is never a reason to allow clipping in the ADC.  If your signal amplitude is out of your ADC range, you can attenuate the signal while it is still in the analog domain, then compensate after acquisition without adding much complexity.
Good luck!

Thank you... but then suppose some minor clipping occurs in Rx generating unwanted signals or products (such as composite triple beats) within the bandwidth of the signal of interest, would these  products add coherently in beamforming or not?

I think the same would apply.  Any phase shift degrades the advantage of the array approach to beam detection and coherence.  However, unlike the TX, you could conceivably recover the full RX signal using some type of correlation, by adding complexity.  Having said this, my gut feeling is that if your problem is having too much signal, the resulting phase shift will probably not significantly affect your ability to receive.

In either case, distortion of the signal degrades the performance;  for TX you will have a less coherent beam, and for RX you will have a less directional receiver.
